# VSTO Get Excel Range and put in Textbox

Tags: c#, .net, excel, winforms, vsto

I created a custom Task Pane with a few inputs on it.  One of the inputs is a textbox.

What I want to do is click on the textbox, then drag select a range of cells and have the range be set to the textbox.

For example, the Conditional Formatting dialog window has this functionality.

What event do I use if I'm changing from my custom task pane to Excel?

[image]

Comment: I have this same problem, and this post is very old, I made a modeless form to do this, but how did you solve the problem? like what I made doesn't imitate the default of the excel.

Comment: @Atreyagaurav What do you mean? The accepted answer should have what you need.

Comment: There are few differences, 1) modeless forms don't have a return feature as the modal forms, so I have no way to use it to return the Range in the runtime easily. (which I had to overcome by customizing the modeless form to do everything independently) 2) It doesn't imitate the excel's default range input because it changes the user's selection; excel has that dotted selection which doesn't change previous selection. & unlike excel which updates while you are dragging the mouse in real-time, this way the value is inserted only when the selection dragging is complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your modeless form, just add an event handler to the WorkSheet.SelectionChanged event.

Something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        ws = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
        ws.SelectionChange += ws_SelectionChange;            

    }

    void ws_SelectionChange(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range Target)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = Target.Address; 
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);
        ws.SelectionChange -= ws_SelectionChange;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps